# Setting argument for kernel extremely slow (OpenCL)

Tags: c++, performance, opencl

In my OpenCL Dijkstra's algorithm implementation, the slowest part by far is writing the 1D reduced graph matrix to the kernel argument, which is global memory.

My graph is a two dimensional array; for OpenCL it gets reduced to a 1D array like so:

```
for (int q = 0; q < numberOfVertices; q++)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < numberOfVertices; t++)
    {
        reducedGraph[q * numberOfVertices + t] = graph[q][t];
    }
}
```

Put into a buffer:

```
cl::Buffer graphBuffer = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, numberOfVertices * numberOfVertices * sizeof(int));
```

**Setting the argument then takes an extremely long time.** For my test with 5,760,000 vertices, writing the data to the argument takes more than 3 seconds while the algorithm itself takes less than a millisecond:

```
kernel_dijkstra.setArg(5, graphBuffer);
```

The kernel uses the graph as a global argument:

```
void kernel min_distance(global int* dist, global bool* verticesSet, const int sizeOfChunks, global int* result, const int huge_int, global int* graph, const int numberOfVertices)
```

Is there any way to speed this up? Thank you!

Edit: My Kernel's code:

```
// Kernel source, calculates minimum distance in segment and relaxes graph.
std::string kernel_code =
       void kernel min_distance(global int* dist, global bool* verticesSet, const int sizeOfChunks, global int* result, const int huge_int, global int* graph, const int numberOfVertices) {
           for (int b = 0; b < numberOfVertices; b++) {
               int gid = get_global_id(0);
               int min = huge_int, min_index = -1;
               for (int v = gid * sizeOfChunks; v < sizeOfChunks * gid + sizeOfChunks; v++) {
                   if (verticesSet[v] == false && dist[v] < min && dist[v] != 0) {
                       min = dist[v];
                       min_index = v;
                    }
               }
               result[gid] = min_index;
               if (gid != 0) continue;
               min = huge_int;
               min_index = -1;
               int current_min;
               for (int a = 0; a < numberOfVertices; a++) {
                   current_min = dist[result[a]];
                   if (current_min < min && current_min != -1 && current_min != 0) { min = current_min; min_index = result[a]; }
               }
               verticesSet[min_index] = true;
     // relax graph with found global min.
               int a = 0;
               int min_dist = dist[min_index];
               int current_dist;
               int compare_dist;
               for (int i = min_index * numberOfVertices; i < min_index * numberOfVertices + numberOfVertices; i++) {
                   current_dist = dist[a];
                   compare_dist = graph[min_index * numberOfVertices + a];
                   if (current_dist > min_dist + compare_dist && !verticesSet[a] && compare_dist != 0) {
                       dist[a] = min_dist + compare_dist;
                   }
                   a++;
               }
           }
       };
```

How I enqueue it:

```
    numberOfComputeUnits = default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>();
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_dijkstra, 0, cl::NDRange(numberOfVertices), numberOfComputeUnits);
```

Comment: Unless my calculations are wrong, 5 million verticies should be allocating a ~100TB buffer. Something about that doesn't seem right, but if it is true, 3 seconds is an extremely quick copy time. Possibly an alternative graph representation would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is that your memory allocation is way too large: 5.76M vertices need a 133TB buffer because the buffer size is quadratic in vertex number. Neither the C++ compiler nor OpenCL will report this as an error and even your kernel will appearently start and run just fine, but in reality it does not compute anything because memory is not enough, and you will get random and undefined results.

Generally `.setArg(...)` should not take longer than a few milliseconds. Also it is beneficial to do the initialization part (containing buffer allocation, `.setArg(...)` etc.) only once in the beginning and then repeatedly run the kernel or exchange data in the buffers without reallocation.

Comment: I was wrong actually, it's fewer vertices. But even so: Do I need to split the graph array and loop over it, calling the kernel again each time? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If the graph really is that large, you have to split it up into batches and compute one after the other. The real questions however should be: Is there a way to make the graph smaller? Maybe by some already known optimizations to Dijkstra? Maybe a smaller graph is sufficient for what you want to accomplish?

Comment: The graph can be of different sizes. 2400 vertices work fine (24 are the max compute units on my device), but 4800 don't. Comparing it with the sequential and an OpenMP implementation, it is much slower at 2400 and can't handle much larger graphs, while the sequential and OpenMP can handle up to about 15000. I was hoping to get a faster result for larger numbers with my GPU, but it doesn't look like it does now.

The graph is only needed for relaxation, so I could move that into its own kernel and only pass the relevant vertex, but I'm not sure if that's worth it.

Comment: Since both your compute time and data scale with the vertex number squared, the GPU might not be beneficial here if you have to move the vertex data across PCIe in every iteration. The data transfer is the bottleneck here. Solution is to avoid memory copy across PCIe by parallelizing the entire thing on the GPU (if possible): Copy input vertex data to GPU memory once in the beginning, let the GPU work on its video memory for lots of iterations, and finally copy the result back to the CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that you are a researcher in this field, thanks a lot for your time. I've added the kernel code to the question, maybe you can have a look and help identify the time sinks? My guess is that the loop is too large and I should reduce it (like with strides of 4 instead of 1), is that correct? Thanks again.

Comment: To identify time sinks, comment out parts of the code & measure execution time. I'd start by checking times for `enqueueWritrBuffer`/`enqueueReadBuffer`/`enqueueNDRangeKernel` first. If memory copy isn't the bottleneck, then check execution times by commenting different parts of the kernel. Regarding the kernel itself, you're not using the index `b` anywhere, so you can probably delete that loop. Also you have a race condition: you read `dist` and also write to it in a non-`gid` memory location, so since all threads are in parallel in random execution order, your results are non-deterministic.